# Option select, doesn't show default

Tags: jquery, html

Default value content1 , but doesn't show " text default show"

please help me..

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('#select123').change(function() {
    jQuery('.content123').hide();
    jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```css
div.content123 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select123">
  <option value="content1">content1</option>

  <option value="content2">content2</option>

  <option value="content3">content3</option>
  <option value="content4">content4</option>
</select>
<div id="content1" class="content123">
  text defult show
</div>

<div id="content2" class="content123">
  contentttttttt
</div>
<div id="content3" class="content123">
  content3
</div>
<div id="content4" class="content123">
  content4
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Fix the markup.

Comment: its not showing because you set the .content123 display: none ; in style
and also hide on jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default doesn't show because the CSS hides all the DIVs. You can trigger a click event on the `select` when the page is loaded so it will show the default.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('#select123').change(function() {
    jQuery('.content123').hide();
    jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).val()).show();
  }).trigger("change");
});
```

```css
div.content123 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select123">
  <option value="content1">content1</option>

  <option value="content2">content2</option>

  <option value="content3">content3</option>
  <option value="content4">content4</option>
</select>
<div id="content1" class="content123">
  text defult show
</div>

<div id="content2" class="content123">
  contentttttttt
</div>
<div id="content3" class="content123">
  content3
</div>
<div id="content4" class="content123">
  content4
</div>
```

Comment: To go minimal and still effective I would simply write *(for example)* **`<option>content1</option>`** instead of **`<option value="content1">content1</option>`** since the option elements' texts match up with their respective values. *For more detail, read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) (If this attribute is omitted, the value is taken from the text content of the option element.).*

Comment: @nyedidikeke I think it's poor style to allow the `value` to default. Also, it could just be because this was a toy example that they're the same, it's probably not the same in the real application.

Comment: I would rather said *based on needs* rather than *poor style*, unless something I don't know about or ignore! Do you mind elaborating further so as to possibly enlighten me?

Comment: @nyedidikeke I think it's just coincidence if the text and value of the option are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add attribute `selected="selected"` to option which you want to make default for `select`.
Then within the script you need to show corresponding `div`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#' + $("#select123").val()).show();
  
  $('#select123').change(function(){
      $('.content123').hide();
      $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
     });
    });
```

```css
div.content123 {
   display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select123">
     <option value="content1" selected="selected">content1</option>

     <option value="content2">content2</option>
     
    <option value="content3">content3</option>
     <option value="content4">content4</option>
    </select>
    <div id="content1" class="content123">
      text defult show
    </div>

    <div id="content2" class="content123">
     contentttttttt
    </div>
    <div id="content3" class="content123">
     content3
    </div>
    <div id="content4" class="content123">
     content4
    </div>
```